Linking error when building libtorch on MacOS
I am going along the pytorch api tutorial and I get the following error
ld: unknown options: --no-as-needed --as-needed --no-as-needed --as-needed
c++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I tried using brew install pytorch to link torch manually, using
g++ example-app.cpp -o out -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pytorch/2.5.1_3/libexec/lib/python3.13/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -std=c++17

But I get this error
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pytorch/2.5.1_3/libexec/lib/python3.13/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/autograd.h:3:10: fatal error: 'torch/csrc/autograd/autograd.h' file not found


torch/csrc/autograd/autograd.h could not be found in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/pytorch/2.5.1_3/libexec/lib/python3.13/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include. Don't you guess why so?

I do not understand what path should I put after -I because I include torch/torch.h in my cpp file, and in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/pytorch/2.5.1_3/libexec/lib/python3.13/site-packages/torch/include/ there is no such header, and this path /opt/homebrew/Cellar/pytorch/2.5.1_3/libexec/lib/python3.13/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include has it, but also results in an error

In the end, I just used a workaround using python3 -c 'import torch;print(torch.utils.cmake_prefix_path)', linking manually seems to be not possible.
